# Equivalence of two definitions of a sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

I don't understand why the definition of a sheaf (Definition 17.3.1 (ii)) given in the book

[KS] **Categories and Sheaves** by Kashiwara and Schapira

is equivalent to the definition of a sheaf (Definition 2.1) given in

[V] Verdier, Exposé II, SGA4, http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/02/02.pdf

To simplify, let me consider only set-valued presheaves.

Here is, in the terminology of [KS], how I understand the two definitions. (Warning: my understanding might be incorrect!)

Let $\mathcal U$ be a universe, let $X$ be a small site and let $F$ be a $\mathcal U$-set-valued presheaf over $X$. Then:

$\bullet\ F$ is sheaf in the sense of [V] if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism for any $A$ in $(\mathcal C_X)^\wedge$, any $U$ in $\mathcal C_X$, and any local isomorphism $f:A\to U$ **which is a monomorphism**,

$\bullet\ F$ is sheaf in the sense of [KS] if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism for any $A$ in $(\mathcal C_X)^\wedge$, any $U$ in $\mathcal C_X$, and any local isomorphism $f:A\to U$.

(The difference is that the local isomorphism $f$ is supposed to be a *monomorphism* in Verdier's definition.)

A "[KS]-sheaf" is of course a "Verdier-sheaf", but I'm unable to prove the converse.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but from KS, given a local epimorphism $f:A\rightarrow U$, the corresponding sieve (denoted $S_A$) is the same as the sieve $S_{\operatorname{Im}(A\rightarrow U)}$. In other words we can replace $A$ by $\operatorname{Im}(A\rightarrow U)$, and thus we can replace $f$ by a monomorphism. Your definition of sheaves is given in terms of local isomorphisms, you can also rephrase it in terms of sieves. Maybe this can help in proving your equivalence.

Comment: @Roland - Thanks! Here is how I (perhaps mistakingly) see things: Let $F$ be a V-sheaf and $f:A\to U$ a local isomorphism. To prove that $F$ is a KS-sheaf, me must show that $F(f)$ is an isomorphism. We can write $f=i\circ p$ with $i$ a monomorphism $p$ an epimorphism. Then $i$ and $p$ are local isomorphisms. As $F$ is a V-sheaf, $F(i)$ is an isomorphism, and it suffices to check that $F(p)$ is an isomorphism. But I don't see why proving that $F(p)$ is an isomorphism is easier than proving that $F(f)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Crossposted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/283233/461

Comment: As requested, here is a link to the MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/283271/6936

Comment: I've just noticed that the equivalence of the definitions follows from Proposition 5.3, implication "(i) $\implies$ (ii bis)", in Verdier’s Exposé http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/02/02.pdf